# Azure AppFabric cache dll version differences

Tags: caching, azure, azure-appfabric

This question might be posted, but nobody pointed out exactly what is the real solution.

- Local setup of Windows Server AppFabric works on minor version (which is 1.0.2912)
- Windows Azure AppFabric SDK 1.0 works on 1.4223
- And AppFabric in cloud works on 1.4223 I think.

Only solution I find to access cloud cache all the time. Which I know is not a good idea.

Any suggestions/links to updated and compatible downloads are welcome.

Comment: Sorry, what's the question here? What specifically is the issue?

Comment: Issue was a mismatch between DLLs, and hence I was not able to test locally with same references which were working in cloud. And vice versa. The issue is resolved with the installation of CTP 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot test Azure AppFabric locally.

**Windows Server AppFabric <> Windows Azure AppFabric**

They are 2 things. Really really different... Today it is mostly only the name that they share...

If you want to test Azure Appfabric it most be the real thing, on-line and yes billable...